# Android development tools

Tags: android, linux

I'd like to hack on my new Android phone using a Linux development environment.

What tools would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using NetBeans with android plugin on ubuntu, because i like the IDE better then Eclipse. If you, however, like(or at least don't mind) Eclipse, i strongly suggest you use it rather then netbeans because the android plugin is more mature and 'user friendly'. For example it has real time resource parsing which is done on save while in netbeans its done only when you compile the project (which is not too convinient for code completion) etc.

instructions about how to install nbandroid can be found [here](http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/pages/Install).

Answer (score 4):

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- http://source.android.com

Answer (score 1):

Volovoy's answer was very succinct, but accurate. Follow the instructions at that site to install Eclipse(Galileo) and the Android SDK (may as well go with the latest) and you are good to go.

There is also a Motorola offering, but I don't know how it compares to the Android SDK. But surely that is what they used to develop the Android 2.0 code for the Droid.

Answer (score 1):

I use both Eclipse and MotoDEvStudio4A

Answer (score 0):

I am using a windows dev setup, but one thing that is very useful is the ASE environment. ASE lets you code in script right on the Android phone. Google has made the ASE available [here.](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html)

Also, Eclipse with the Android plugin makes the ide choice easy for Windows. I don't know if Eclipse works on Linux.